# when i try to use apt-get to download packages or files it shows an error

Tags: apt

Error with my source list file. Ive tried all online forums and nothing has worked. any help would be much appreciated.

Output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/beaver.list`:

```
#Manage apt's list of trusted keys

  apt-key add <file>          - add the key contained in <file> ('-' for stdin)
  apt-key del <keyid>         - remove the key <keyid>
  apt-key export <keyid>      - output the key <keyid>
  apt-key exportall           - output all trusted keys
  apt-key update              - update keys using the keyring package
  apt-key net-update          - update keys using the network
  apt-key list                - list keys
  apt-key finger              - list fingerprints
  apt-key adv                 - pass advanced options to gpg (download key)

#If no specific keyring file is given the command applies to all keyring files.
```

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: if i try to `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` to get tkinter i get this error ```N: Ignoring file 'beaver.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type 'apt-key' is not known on line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/beaver.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
N: Ignoring file 'beaver.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type 'apt-key' is not known on line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/beaver.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.```

Comment: How did you create that file?  Because that file has the output of the apt-key help info, and is NOT a valid apt sources file.  (Remove the file)

Comment: how to i remove it safely and i think it was when i dual booted my laptop that the errros occured

Answer (score 0):

assuming command line `sudo rm -iv beaver.list.save.1` in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ should work.

Help on CLI deletion is at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DeletingFiles
-v for verbosity and if required, -i for interactive confirmation of what is happening. You may need to  -ivf to force

update : (sorry can't comment) : did you `sudo` at the start of the command - this forces superuser permissions and can force file deletion (-ivf). you will need to provide your password (as an administrator)
If you have a "normal" user you would need to `su [admin user name]` first then issue the command - or logout/switch user from the drop down top right and login as your [admin user]

Comment: hi thanks but this hasnt changed anything if i try to rm filename it says permission denied.